# Stop asking for password so often?

Tags: macos, password

Is there a way to make Mac OS X ask for my password less frequently?  For instance, I frequently have to re-enter my password into the Mac App Store.  Are there any tools or tweaks to tell the system to remember my password (maybe in the keychain), or to make the system ask for my password less frequently in other situations?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OS X Mountain Lion makes it impossible to do that, because of Security Reasons. You can’t store your Mac App Store password or iTunes Store password in the keychain. For everything else, there’s [1Password](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/1password-password-manager/id443987910?mt=12).